# Windows7 - ewf - control user's interface language

Tags: windows-7

I am developing an application for Windows Embedded Standard, which uses EWF to protect the c:\ drive.

I want to be able to control the user's UI language, which is set by this registry key
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PreferredUILanguages

The key needs to be set before the user logins in. However, we are using autologin.

I have tried to set the key as a ScheduledTask, to be run as that user on system startup. However, the task doesn't run before autologin starts.

I have also tried to write program that runs in the \HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Execute. However, those programs run  in the NT-System, not the Win32-Subsystem, and have a different API, which I don't have experience of writing for.

Is there a method to control the PreferredUILanguages setting when EWF is in place?

Comment: Delay autologin?

Comment: There's no standard way of delaying autologin. I've found a 3rd party tool that will do that, but it's $2/device

Answer (score 0):

You needs to write a value to the default user profile. All new profiles will inherit it.

```
reg load HKLM\temp C:\Users\Default\ntuser.dat
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\temp\Control Panel\Desktop /v PreferredUILanguages /d en-US /t REG_SZ /f
(put here as many commands as you wish)
reg unload HKLM\temp
```

Of course, this will apply if the user profile is not created yet.

You can also setup a GPO that will apply to all user profiles at logon. That is the best way here:

```
Administrative Templates (Users) > Regional and Language Options > Restricts the UI languages Windows should use for the selected user
```

**Additional info**

Registry: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2012/04/25/tip-49-how-do-you-set-default-user-profile-registry-settings/

GPO:
https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Globalization::LockUserUILanguage

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear enough. What I want to do is have an application that can change the user's PreferredUILanguages when the C:\ is protected by EWF. Any changes made to this key are lost when the machine restarts.

Comment: GPO is designed to apply changes at every logon. That is what used all over the world, so, that you always have the setting in place.

If you choose the above registry method it will apply to the new user profile at first logon and won't be lost after machine restart.

Comment: What I want to do, is to read a setting from the D:\ (not protected by EWF), and then apply it to the user's registry. And do this before the user is autologged in.  My app will change this setting when required.

Comment: @CSM Do you need to re-apply this settings every time? Can we read this setting once, put it to the default user profile and apply it once to every new user profile at first logon?

Comment: There is only one user. I want to apply the setting on each boot, until the user changes what setting she wants applied. Then the new setting should be applied at the next & subsequent boots

Comment: @CSM OK, the only way then would be to run a logon script (no matter from AD server GPO or with Task manager). This script should read the value from disk and write in to the registry. This will apply in few seconds after the user logon.

Comment: Thanks for your time, @Hardoman. But unfortunately the key needs to be applied before login

Comment: @CSM The last option for you is to run the script with Task scheduler at PC start and write it to HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1752339473-2879811872-921144444-1115, where random digits is a SID or your known user. This key will be copied to HKCU after user logon.